# MySql vs Postgresql view creation

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I am having this view query in MySql which works

```
SELECT s.id AS id,
       s.customer_id AS customer_id,
       s.shipment_status_id AS shipment_status_id,
       ss.name AS shipment_status_name,
       s.ship_from_date AS ship_from_date,
       s.ship_to_company AS ship_to_company,
       s.ship_from_company AS ship_from_company,
       s.ship_to_address1 AS ship_to_address1,
       s.ship_to_address2 AS ship_to_address2,
       s.ship_to_postal_code AS ship_to_postal_code,
       s.ship_to_city AS ship_to_city,
       c.country AS country,
       p.tracking_numbers AS tracking_numbers,
       s.quote_service_name AS quote_service_name,
       s.quote_total_charge AS quote_total_charge,
       p.weight AS weight,
       p.insurance_amount AS insurance_amount,
       p.cod_amount AS cod_amount,
       z.fedex AS ZONE,
       s_p.code AS state_province_code,
       s_p.zone AS state_province_zone,
       ss.name AS status_name,
       i.total AS total,
       cust.first_name AS customer_first_name,
       cust.last_name AS customer_last_name,
       (CASE
            WHEN (s.additional_services_saturday_delivery = 1) THEN 'Yes'
        END) AS saturday_delivery,
       (CASE
            WHEN (s.additional_services_hold_for_pickap = 1) THEN 'Yes'
        END) AS hold_for_pickap,
       (CASE
            WHEN (s.ship_to_residential = 1) THEN 'Yes'
        END) AS ship_to_residential,
       (CASE
            WHEN (s.additional_services_signature_required = 1) THEN 'Yes'
        END) AS signature_required
FROM (((((((shipments s
            LEFT JOIN shipment_package_group_data p on((s.id = p.shipment_id)))
           LEFT JOIN country c on((s.ship_to_country_id = c.id)))
          LEFT JOIN invoice i on((s.invoice_id = i.id)))
         LEFT JOIN state_province s_p on((s.ship_to_state = s_p.id)))
        LEFT JOIN shipment_statuses ss on((s.shipment_status_id = ss.id)))
       LEFT JOIN zones z on((s.zone_id = z.id)))
      JOIN customer cust on((s.customer_id = cust.id)))
GROUP BY s.id
```

But when I try converting it to PostgreSQL view like this:

```
    SELECT s.id AS id,
       s.customer_id AS customer_id,
       s.shipment_status_id AS shipment_status_id,
       ss.name AS shipment_status_name,
       s.ship_from_date AS ship_from_date,
       s.ship_to_company AS ship_to_company,
       s.ship_from_company AS ship_from_company,
       s.ship_to_address1 AS ship_to_address1,
       s.ship_to_address2 AS ship_to_address2,
       s.ship_to_postal_code AS ship_to_postal_code,
       s.ship_to_city AS ship_to_city,
       c.country AS country,
       p.tracking_numbers AS tracking_numbers,
       s.quote_service_name AS quote_service_name,
       s.quote_total_charge AS quote_total_charge,
       p.weight AS weight,
       p.insurance_amount AS insurance_amount,
       p.cod_amount AS cod_amount,
       z.fedex AS ZONE,
       s_p.code AS state_province_code,
       s_p.zone AS state_province_zone,
       ss.name AS status_name,
       i.total AS total,
       cust.first_name AS customer_first_name,
       cust.last_name AS customer_last_name,
       (CASE
            WHEN (s.additional_services_saturday_delivery = 1) THEN 'Yes'
        END) AS saturday_delivery,
       (CASE
            WHEN (s.additional_services_hold_for_pickap = 1) THEN 'Yes'
        END) AS hold_for_pickap,
       (CASE
            WHEN (s.ship_to_residential = 1) THEN 'Yes'
        END) AS ship_to_residential,
       (CASE
            WHEN (s.additional_services_signature_required = 1) THEN 'Yes'
        END) AS signature_required
FROM (shipments s
            LEFT JOIN shipment_package_group_data p on(s.id::INT = p.shipment_id)
           LEFT JOIN country c on((s.ship_to_country_id = c.id))
          LEFT JOIN invoice i on((s.invoice_id = i.id))
         LEFT JOIN state_province s_p on((s.ship_to_state::INT = s_p.id))
        LEFT JOIN shipment_statuses ss on((s.shipment_status_id = ss.id))
       LEFT JOIN zones z on((s.zone_id = z.id))
      JOIN customer cust on((s.customer_id = cust.id)))
GROUP BY s.id
```

PostgreSQL complains the following:

```
    [Err] ERROR:  column "ss.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 4:        ss.name AS shipment_status_name,
               ^
```

Comment: It's not very clear why you are grouping at all.  Furthermore, this is one of MySQL's big mistakes (not to say sins), to allow incomplete `GROUP BY` clauses, which will behave somehow.  In PostgreSQL, you have to at least list all primary keys of the tables involved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR** MySQL is ignoring the SQL Standard and allowing your original query to return indeterminate results. Postgres doesn't let you do that; you will need to properly define what results you expect.

You can see an explanation of the behavior that MySQL is relying on e.g. in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594865/why-does-mysql-add-a-feature-that-conflicts-with-sql-standards). When you convert your query over to Postgres, you need to fill in what the author of the original query neglected: there is a `GROUP BY s.id`, so for each `s.id` that is grouped-by, which `ss.name` must be returned? There may be several different `ss.name` values, how should the database decide which one to give you? Note that `ss.name` is not the only offending column in this query, all of your non-aggregate columns you are SELECTing potentially need to be handled properly in this query.

Ultimately, you will need to use some combination of:

- get rid of the `GROUP BY` entirely and simply return all results
- `GROUP BY` **all** non-aggregated columns you are `SELECT`ing, e.g. `GROUP BY s.id, s.customer_id, s.shipment_status_id, ...`
- Use `SELECT ... DISTINCT ON ... ORDER BY` to tell Postgres that you only care to receive a single `s.customer_id`, `s.shipment_status_id`, `ss.name`, etc. for each `s.id` that you are `GROUP`ing by. The `ORDER BY` will instruct Postgres how to decide which one of each `s.customer_id` etc. to return.

... and probably there are some more workarounds I'm neglecting, but that should get you started in the right direction.